# XSL for each on the xml being transformed inside a for each of parm

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have the following xml

```
  <root>
      <element id='1'>blah</element>
      <element id='2'>blah</element>
      <element id='3'>blah</element>
  </root>
```

A parm passed into my xsl that is..

```
  <Ids>
      <id>1</id>
      <id>2</id>
      <id>3</id> 
  </Ids>
```

In my xsl I want to loop through both the parm and xml to match any elements with id attribute that equals one of the parm id values.This is dynamic and I will not know the values of either they will be uuids.

I've tried this but I the of element id is not found

```
  <xsl:for-each  select="/$Ids/id">
 <xsl:variable name="driverId" select="."/>
     <xsl:for-each select="/root/element[@id=$driverId]">
          //do something
     </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:for-each>
```

If message out the value of element id before the first for each I can see all the values but not with in the loop.. Is this possible in the way I'm thinking about doing it.

Still not working, I've changed the to
       
same  results.

In the xsl if I put outside the parm for-each

```
  <test><xsl:for-each select="/root/element/@id"></test>
```

I get

```
  <test>1 2 3</test>
```

IF put

```
  <test><xsl:for-each select="/root/element/@id"></test>
```

inside

```
   <xsl:for-each  select="$Ids/id">
```

I get nothing returned???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a key

```
<xsl:key name="id" match="element" use="@id"/>
```

then you also need a reference to the primary input document with a global `xsl:variable` i.e.

```
<xsl:variable name="main-root" select="/"/>
```

once you have that use

```
<xsl:for-each select="$Ids//id">
  <xsl:for-each select="key('id', ., $main-root)">...</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Without a key you need

```
<xsl:for-each select="$Ids//id">
  <xsl:for-each select="$main-root/root/element[@id = current()]">...</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: I tried the "without" version... still same problem I will try the keys now

Comment: Thanks, Martin setting the variable and the key worked!!! I was able to use my "inside" variable driverId to hold onto the instance of id to use in the second for each and substring.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <xsl:for-each  select="/$Ids/id">
> ```

**Obviously incorrect**:

`/$Ids` isn't syntactically legal -- a variable/parameter reference cannot immeditely follow the `/` operator.

**A correct expression would be**:

```
$Ids/id
```

**And what you actually want is**:

```
/root/element[@id=$Ids/id]
```

Comment: I'm able to get the values of $IDs in this way I have tried without the "/" .  I'm sending the parm from java as document.getDocumentElement()

Comment: @JustinCox, OK, then just remove the `/Ids` from the expressions in my answer -- I'll update it, too.

Comment: My problem is with the xml being transformed seems like I lose reference to the "/root/element[@id=$driverId]" inside the for each loop of the parm does this make any sense to you. Thanks

Comment: @JustinCox, This problem doesn't exist if you use the expression from this anser: `<xsl:for-each="/root/element[@id=$Ids/id]"/>`

Comment: I update my question I tried with the changing the expression, but even on a simple print out of element attribute inside the first parm for each I don't get any results(even without trying to equal the ids)